# IIS6 - Change the language to English

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6, language-packs

I have a Windows 2003 VM Image which was created by a Swedish Windows Install. Afterwards the language settings of the machine was changed to English. However, I just added IIS6 Windows component to the machine (from Add/Remove Programs) - IIS6 is not in English. It's in Swedish.

IIS Manager's Menu options are in English, but the Title Bar uses hanteraren(Swedish for Manager). The IIS Error pages come in Swedish. How do I get IIS's default language back in English.

Answer (score 1):

You reinstall/install new with an English version.

[I'm assuming you've followed the steps here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924852) to change the language settings on the OS (default input language and installed services), which is the primary supported option for [mostly] changing the OS language.  The other way is to buy and install a MUI pack (Multilingual User Interface Pack), which does a tolerable job (though I can't say from experience whether or not it will help your issue), or ideally, install the OS in the language of your choice from the start.

Honestly, kind of disappointing and unhelpful, but I suppose wanting to change the OS language isn't a common enough concern to warrant development time to make it work well.

Comment: I reinstall/install new 'what' with an English Version?

Comment: @user93353 Operating system.  Reinstall/install new English version of the OS.

Comment: :-) - Why don't I just buy a new machine which comes preinstalled with the English version of the OS.

Comment: @user93353 Buying a new box is an option, but I'd hope a new box would come with a slightly more up-to-date OS than 2003.  Point being though, that Microsoft doesn't really provide a good (free) way to swap OS languages in 2003 or XP.  And even in the newer OSes where they do, they charge you extra for the privilege.  Maybe see if you can get the company to spring for Swedish language immersion training instead of buying an MUI.  Stokholm's really a very lovely city.

Comment: The whole OS is in English now. Except for IIS. That was the question. I am not sure if that means that there is no way to swap OS languages in 2003.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an IIS expert by any means, but since you say the menu options are fine but the error pages and title bar are still in Swedish, it might be the globalization options that need changed.

See here for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28VS.71%29.aspx

See the answer/comment on this SO question as a reference too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11136251/135026

Comment: I added `<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en" />` in web.config - but didn't make any difference.

Comment: have you tried adding this to the machine.config? web.config is app specific isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

**Stapes for Changing the Default ASP Language (IIS 6.0)**

The default ASP language affects ASP files that do not use the <%@Language%> directive. Changing the default ASP language corresponds to the metabase setting, AspScriptLanguage Metabase Property.

> Important

   You must be a Administrators on the local computer to perform this stapes. As a security best practice, log on to your computer by using an account that is not in the Administrators group, and then use the runas command to run IIS Manager as an administrator. At a command prompt, type runas /user:Administrative_AccountName "mmc %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\iis.msc".
  **To change the default ASP language**

In IIS Manager, double-click the local computer, right-click the starting-point directory of the application you want to configure, and then click Properties.

Click the Directory tab, and then click Configuration.

Click the Options tab.

In the Application configuration section, in the Default ASP language box, type the language you want to use.

Click OK.

Comment: The default ASP language refers to the programming language not spoken or written language. i.e. it currently shows VBScript for me - what do you suggest changing it to? I really don't think this will work. I want to change the language in which error messages will appear.